# jQuery.inArray(), returns -1 even if it contains the value in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

The inarray function returns -1 even if it has the value in my array
for eg. if I have `['3','7','43','44','45','46']` in my array, when I select a value 3 or 7 it shows correct answer and then when I select other values it returns -1.

my jQuery coding:

```
$(document).on("change", '#level',function() {
  var valu = $('#level').val(); 
  $.each(filterResults, function(index, item) {
    if(jQuery.inArray(valu , item.id)!==-1){ //item.id has all array values
      //my functions
      }
    }
});
```

then my HTML coding

```
<select class="tb2" name="level" id="level">
  <option value="">Select Level</option>
  <option value="3">Pre Test</option>
  <option value="7">Level 1</option>
  <option value="43">Level 2</option>
  <option value="44">Level 3</option>
  <option value="45">Level 4</option>
  <option value="46">Level 5</option>
</select>
```

console.log(valu,item.id) returns

44 3

44 7

44 43

44 44

44 45

44 46

Comment: Why use `jQuery.inArray` when you already use `$` everywhere else? And why not use the native `indexOf()` function?

Comment: What is `filterResults`? `item.id has all array values` - are you sure? Because in a fiddle it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/zopg3gen/

Comment: Show us the output of `console.log(valu, item.id)` (copy/paste them into your question). We cannot answer your question without knowing what the values contain.

Comment: filterResults will get the all the values from db. and item .id will store the ids got from the db.

Comment: console.log(valu, item.id) returns 
44 3

44 7

44 43

44 44

44 45

44 46

Comment: Okay. Those do not look like iterable values; they look like numbers/strings. `jQuery.inArray()` expects an array as the second argument.

Comment: "`console.log(valu, item.id)` returns 44 3 44 7 44 43 44 44 44 45 44 46" What is expected result ?

Comment: If you still have not gotten your answer, what would be super beneficial for us to help you, would be to include the results of `filterResults`, only then we can see what you are exactly trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(jQuery.inArray(valu , filterResults)!==-1)
```

without `.each()`

```js
var filterResults = ['3','7','43','44','45','46'];

$(document).on("change", '#level',function() {
  var valu = $('#level').val(); 
//  $.each(filterResults, function(index, item) {
    if(jQuery.inArray(valu , filterResults)!==-1){ 
      //my functions
      console.log(valu, $.inArray(valu, filterResults))
      }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select class="tb2" name="level" id="level">
  <option value="">Select Level</option>
  <option value="3">Pre Test</option>
  <option value="7">Level 1</option>
  <option value="43">Level 2</option>
  <option value="44">Level 3</option>
  <option value="45">Level 4</option>
  <option value="46">Level 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`item.id` does not contain an array, but a single `id`. `$.inArray` only works with arrays. Try this instead:

```
$(document).on("change", '#level',function() {
   var valu = $('#level').val(); 
   $.each(filterResults, function(index, item) {
       if(valu == item.id){ // if item.id is equal to valu (e.g. '7' == '7')
           // some code
       }
   });
});
```

Alternatively, you could filter the results using [$.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) to find out if the id is in there:

```
$(document).on("change", '#level',function() {
   var valu = $('#level').val(); 
   if( $.grep(filterResults, function(){return this.id == valu}).length ){
       // some code
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem in your code is that you are iterating through the results array for no reason. $.inArray, will already iterate though the array without you having to do the work; if the value exists, it will return the index of the item, if not, it will return -1. With that being said, this is what you should do:

```
var filterResults = ['3', '7', '43', '44', '45', '46'];
$('#level').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if ($.inArray(value, filterResults) > -1) { 
        console.log(value + " EXISTS IN ARRAY");
    } else {
        console.log("FALSE");
    }
});
```

**[Here's a FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4zte4ggu/)** for further help.